# Excel VBA ODBC connection failed

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2010 VBA to retrieve data from MS Access 2010 with ODBC connection to SQL Server R2 Express, in my previous machine there is no issue (32bit platform) but when I got new machine it's always said "ODBC connection to (odbc name) failed -2147467259".

From Access 2010 to SQL there is no issue, but when I retrieve data from Excel always trigger this error.

I have check the permission for the user (DBO), all the app in the same machine, all the services are on, ODBC setting is correct. During the execution of the script all OK except when the line is opening the table.

```
Function RetrieveProjectList()
Dim strConn As String
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rec As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim intColCount As Integer
Dim strName As String
Dim strSQL As String

On Error GoTo Error_Trap
strName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\DBSource V0.1.accdb"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
strConn = "Provider=microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0;"
strConn = strConn & "Data Source=" & strName & ";"
conn.Open ConnectionString:=strConn
Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL = "SELECT qryProjectList.* " & _
    "FROM qryProjectList ORDER BY tblArea.AreaName,tblProject.ProjectName;"

rec.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
'Retrieve data from Access
rec.MoveFirst
If rec.Fields.count <> 0 Then
```

After syntax "rec.open ...." the error pop up.
In other machince are OK.

Question:

Is this related to OS version 64bit? What did I miss out here?
Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks, seageath

Comment: Are you saying that when you use your code in Excel to get data from Access, it works, but when you use your Excel code to get data from SQL Server, it doesn't work?

Comment: Your old machine was 32 bit. Does that mean your new one is 64 bit?